# input composite video/audio to Skype?

Tags: skype, video-streaming, video-chat

I'd like to use and external composite video and stereo audio source as input Skype on my Windows desktop and laptop.

I'd be starting out with three RCA connectors...

Is there an RCA/audio two USB converter suited to do this?
ideally, an external USB dongle would be  :")

Has anyone some experience inputting through USB?